# How do I change the font size of a UILabel in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, uilabel

`label.font.pointSize` is read-only, so I'm not sure how to change it.

Comment: extension UILabel{
    
    func font(size: CGFloat){
        
        self.font = UIFont(descriptor: self.font.fontDescriptor, size: size)
        
    }
}

Answer (score 695, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 20)
```

Or like this:

```
label.font = label.font.withSize(20)
```

This will use the same font. 20 can be whatever size you want of course.

**Note:** The latter option will overwrite the current font weight to `regular` so if you want to preserve the font weight use the first option.

**Swift 3 Update**:

```
label.font = label.font.withSize(20)
```

**Swift 4 Update**:

```
label.font = label.font.withSize(20)
```

or

```
label.font = UIFont(name:"fontname", size: 20.0)
```

and if you use the system fonts

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
label.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
```

Comment: This does in-fact change the pointSize property the font. However, the pointSize gets immediately reset to 17.0 before the label gets redrawn. So there's a bit more to it than that to actually see a different font size on the screen.

Comment: Are you setting the font to 17 anywhere? Storyboard?

Comment: I ran it on my iPhone 5 and your code works. It must be a bug in the simulator.

Comment: That's interesting. Not really surprised to see another bug though. Glad it's working

Comment: There's seriously something wrong with documentation when i just googled this instead of just looking it up because I knew it would be faster.

Comment: This is good for iOS developers, but for the sake of those googling this question, I will add the note that UIFont does not exist on OSX's version of Cocoa. On OS X you'll want something like label.font=NSFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 20)

Comment: regarding the "17", perhaps that was simply **autoshrink** working.

Comment: How do you change the font size for the label in table cells?

Comment: extension UILabel{
    
    func font(size: CGFloat){
        
        self.font = UIFont(descriptor: self.font.fontDescriptor, size: size)
        
    }
}

Comment: `label.font = UIFont(name:"fontname", size: 20.0)` doesn't do anything in Swift 5 (at least in the emulator, can't test with a real iOS device), use `label.font = label.font.withSize(20)` instead.

Answer (score 73):

I think the best way to do this - if keeping the same font that is already assigned to the `UILabel`  would be:

(using Swift)

```
label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(20)
```

(using Swift 3)

```
label.font = label.font.withSize(20)
```

Ideally I would set this in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method, as it doesn't need to change every time the view appears.

Answer (score 40):

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
```

Comment: label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)      // in swift 3

Comment: This solution will not work for custom fonts. It will always return system font.

Answer (score 24):

We can set font as per our requirement like,

```
label.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 15.0)
label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15)
label.font = UIFont.italicSystemFontOfSize(15)
label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want just change size of your font i create this extension

```
// Add extension

extension UILabel {
    func setSizeFont (sizeFont: Double) {
        self.font =  UIFont(name: self.font.fontName, size: sizeFont)!
        self.sizeToFit()
    }
}

// Use

myLabel.setSizeFont(60)
```

Comment: This helped me. I changed the font size, its working in swift 4.

Answer (score 6):

You can give like this also

```
labelName.font = UIFont(name: "systemFont", size: 30)
```

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 3 again...

```
myLabel.font = myLabel.font.withSize(18)
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to use custom font with bold option:

```
nameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "GillSans-Bold", size: 27)
```

Answer (score 3):

In swift3, 
suppose your UILable name is myLable and you want to change its font size
do this

```
myLable.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift-3.1**

label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an extension.

```
import UIKit

extension UILabel {

    func sizeFont(_ size: CGFloat) {
        self.font = self.font.withSize(size)
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
self.myLabel.fontSize(100)
```

Answer (score 2):

Apple keep changing things for no reason:
Swift 4+:

```
myLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
```

thanks apple for wasting people time to figure out what "font size" methods they need to use!

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
label.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0)

label.font = UIFont(name:"Helvetica Neue", size: 20.0)//Set your font name here
```

Through Story board

To display multiple lines set 0(Zero), this will display more than one line in your label.

If you want to display only 2 lines set 2.

[image]

If you want to set minimum font size for label **Click Autoshrink** and **Select Minimum Font Size** option

See below screens

[image]

Here set minimum font size

**EX: 9 (In this image)**

If your label get more text at that time your label text will be shrink upto 9

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2**

```
myLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `fontWithSize` for a label with light system font, but it changes back to normal system font.

If you want to keep the font's traits, better to include the descriptors.

`label.font = UIFont(descriptor: label.font.fontDescriptor(), size: 16.0)`

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3:

```
label = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
```

and to use system preset sizes, for example:

```
label = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.smallSystemFontSize)
```

Comment: I think you forgot label.font

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

```
label.font.withSize(16)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.1

```
import UIKit

extension UILabel {
    var fontSize: CGFloat {
        get {
            return self.font.pointSize
        }
        set {
            self.font =  UIFont(name: self.font.fontName, size: newValue)!
            self.sizeToFit()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`swift 4:`

```
label.font = UIFont("your font name", size: 15)
```

also if you want to set the label font in all views in your project try this in `appDelegate>didFinishLaunch`:
`UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont("your font name", size: 15)`

Answer (score -1):

**SWIFT 3.1**

Label.font = Label.font.withSize(NewValue)

Comment: This is not correct, and is not written using Cocoa naming conventions.

Answer (score -1):

It's very easy and convenient to change font size from storyboard, and you can instantly see the result of the change.

Actually, it's also very easy to change other font attributes on storyboard too, like style, font family, etc.

[image]