# How do I change the size of text?

Tags: ios, swift

I can't figure out how to change the text size. I can change the font to .largeTitle but that's as big as the text will get.

Comment: Try this for UILabel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24356906/14351818

Comment: For SwiftUI's Text, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56465243/14351818

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using UIKit:

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: .medium)
```

If you're using SwiftUI:

```
Text("something")
.font(.system(size: 10, weight: .light))
```